# How to create own method of atan(arc tangent)?

Tags: decimal

I am using c# decimal for high accuracy project but was stuck at the Atan method because it only accept double. Converting decimal into double will cause a data lose so I am hoping to write my own atan method. Can someone show me how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel, you can use the DecimalMath class, which has an Atan method, the parameter of the method is decimal and the method returns a decimal too. Read more [here](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Reference/Extreme.Mathematics.DecimalMath.Atan.aspx).

If you absolutely want to reinvent the wheel and make an implementation yourself, this formula might be useful for you:

**arctan(z) = ((z^1)/1)-((z^3)/3)+((z^5)/5)+(((-1)^((2*n)-1))*(((2*n)-1)/((2*n)-1)))**

The bigger n is, the more exact is your result.